# Java Android - Redmi 3 (MIUI) - Notification icons cannot be changed?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to change notification icons and in emulator it is OK :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what I want (tested on emulator API level 22 (android 5.1.1)) BUT, when i'm running this APP in my real phone (Xiaomi Redmi 3 prime with MIUI 8.0.1) also android 5.1.1 - the notifications looks very very very differant. This notification icons does not showing (just a default application icon).

But... why? What can i do now?

Here is my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(compat);
        b.setSmallIcon((state == STATE_STOPPED) ? R.drawable.ic_stat_remove : R.drawable.check);
        b.setContentText(content);
        b.setContentTitle(BASE_NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
        b.setOngoing(true);
        b.setAutoCancel(true);
        b.setColor((state == STATE_STOPPED) ? Color.RED : Color.rgb(22, 219, 28));

        NotificationManager m = (NotificationManager) compat.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        m.notify(0, b.build());
```

Just a very simple notification... can someone tell me, what's wrong? Or just MIUI turns off all notification icons and set it to default app launch icons?

Thanks!

EDIT: notification in my phone looks like this...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is behavior of MIUI system. You can not display different icons in notification, by default it takes app icon as notification icon.

Comment: its happened to me one year back. Can you accept this answer so if any one came to know about MIUI.

Comment: I have the same "freak" issue with a Xiaimi Redmi Note 3. By debug I found that inside the Notification there's a field called ExtraNotification of type MiUiNotification,  and inside this, there's a flag: customizedIcon=false. Maybe if this flag is changed, then a personalized icon can be displayed.

Comment: @JuanPablo is there something similar regarding custom layouts?  Those don't seem to be showing properly either.

Comment: @JuanPablo you are saved me :) Looked a solution for the problem for a week, lot of time spent for nothing... finally found your answer and fixed the problem in minutes! Thanks man!

Comment: @Mark do you still have problem with custom layouts?

Comment: @Alex I no longer use custom layouts in MIUI, so I don't know if it's still a problem in general.

Comment: @Mark Just in case you interesting - setCustomContentView() and setCustomBigContentView() works OK for me with MIUI, no problems at all with NotificationCompat.Builder and targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Which versions of MIUI can you confirm are working?

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately, Google Play console does not provide the info about MIUI version. For to fix the bug with status bar icons, I worked with customers with  Redmi 4X and Redmi Note 5A, both with original MIUI launchers. They provided screens the notification content with my custom layouts and it looked as expected.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, but Juan Pablo (in comment [Java Android - Redmi 3 (MIUI) - Notification icons cannot be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146059/java-android-redmi-3-miui-notification-icons-cannot-be-changed#comment68219626_40146180)) gave me a clue and now I have a solution:

```
//notification is an object of class android.app.Notification
    try {
        Class miuiNotificationClass = Class.forName("android.app.MiuiNotification");
        Object miuiNotification = miuiNotificationClass.newInstance();
        Field field = miuiNotification.getClass().getDeclaredField("customizedIcon");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        field.set(miuiNotification, true);
        field = notification.getClass().getField("extraNotification");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        field.set(notification, miuiNotification);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Now it works as it is expected.

Comment: @sikor Is there any documentation on all available `android.app.MiuiNotification` methods and fields?

Comment: @jkasten I haven't found any. I spent some time for searching something about this and all I have found was this: http://www.bkjia.com/Androidjc/1119525.html

Comment: @sikor great find. it must be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Man, you save my life